# NullPointerException in filter

Tags: spring

I'm running a filter with every request where I check for "X-Company-ID" header. The header is only sent on login reqest and afterwards the CompanyContext currentCompany is set from the current user data.

Here is my filter, I added some print lines to understand what's going on:

```
@Component
public class CORSFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    private CompanyService companyService;

    @Autowired
    public CORSFilter(CompanyService companyService) {
        this.companyService = companyService;
    }

    public CORSFilter() {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, PATCH, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, authorization, accept, content-type, content-disposition," +
                "x-requested-with, remember-me, Pragma, Cache-Control, If-Modified-Since, X-Auth-Token, X-Company-ID, X-Client-Certificate");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "X-Auth-Token, X-Company-ID, Content-Disposition");

        String companyHeader = request.getHeader("X-Company-ID");
        System.out.println("Company header: " + companyHeader);
        if (companyHeader != null && !ObjectUtils.isEmpty(companyHeader)) {
            System.out.println("Company header 2: " + companyHeader);
            Company company = companyService.getCompanyByDomainIdentifier(companyHeader);
            if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(company) || company != null) {
                System.out.println(company.getCompanyName());
                CompanyContext.setCurrentCompany(company.getId());
            }
        }

        if (!request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS")) {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }
}
```

The output goes as follows:

```
Company header: 2
Company header 2: 2
Avantirent OÜ
Company header: 2
Company header 2: 2
2020-02-05 16:17:29.930 ERROR 6124 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.bitweb.syda.config.filter.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
```

If I understand correctly- the first time the filter runs it gets the header and the right company. The second time it gets the header but getting the company gives me a NullPointerException.

The exception comes from the line `Company company = companyService.getCompanyByDomainIdentifier(companyHeader);` which is either a correct Company or null. I don't do anything with it if it's null, but it still gives me a NullPointerException.

I'm really stuck here, any help?

Comment: yes it is null always, in spring it always looks for a default constructor. Hence you are getting it as null.

Comment: How though? The first time around it correctly outputs "Avantirent OÜ" (company name)

Comment: Try creating the bean in your configuraiton folder and then autowire it here. That should fix your problem

Comment: The issue is not with your company header. THe `companyService` is null

Comment: Probably it has something to do with the bean creation order. One time CompanyService is created before CORSFilter and the ctor with `@Autowired` is used. Next time CORSFilter bean is first to be created an the empty ctor is used. Try to remove the default constructor (and make `companyService` final).

Comment: I autowired CompanyService in my WebSecurifyConfig (where I have my filter chain) and passed it into the filter (new CORSFilter(companyService)) and now it seems to be working. Thanks guys.